# Changing the order of a matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix

```
test = np.array([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,0]])
```

How do I reorder the columns so that they are like this matrix? (Basically the last row becomes the first row in reverse order and so on...)

```
np.array([[0,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0]])
```

Comment: `np.flip(test)`? Or just `test[::-1, ::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Update (ahh... Okay, I think I understand now.)

You can use negative steps for both the inner and outer steps.

```
test[::-1, ::-1]
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: True. But that doesn't reverse the order of the rows that I am looking for.

Comment: The OP also  needs the columns reversed

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse both axis

```
test[::-1,::-1]
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse both the row and column you can use the `np.flip`, in your case:

```py
test = np.array([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,0]])
reversed = np.flip(test, axis=[0,1])
```